# Ember: Building app into single js, css file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am using ember-cli v1.13.8. Ember builds the app into application-name.js and vendor.js and similar named css files. Is there a way to build them into single js and css files, so that in my index.html I can reference just one js and css file instead of two for each?

Comment: Not really related, but maybe you should look at this shiny new pre-release that will attempt to change a lot of things in the near future: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an addon for that [ember-cli-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-concat).

Basic usage is

```
ember install ember-cli-concat
```

Refer the [wiki](https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-cli-concat/wiki) for complete information on using this addon.